# Group policy lock screen is not updating when the picture changes

Tags: group-policy, windows-10

I have a group policy that looks in C:\background\defaultBackground.jpg for the lock screen.  When I set the policy and did a gpupdate, restarted, logged in, and then logged back out the picture was there.  However, when I changed the picture it is not updating.  Does anybody have some insight as to why?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Is this Windows 10 Pro?  And is this Windows 10 v1607 or later (the Anniversary Update)?

The lock screen policy now only works in Enterprise or Education SKUs.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/manage/group-policies-for-enterprise-and-education-editions

Answer (score 0):

My guess is because this is a computer setting and isn't applied at logon/logoff of the user but at computer startup or at the GP refresh interval. My guess is that you changed the image and then logged off and on and expected the image to change.